# How can I hide children of draft pages using wp_list_pages()?

Tags: wp-list-pages, children

I'm displaying a simple sitemap with *wp_list_pages();*

```
$args = array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'title_li' => '',
    'post_status'  => 'publish'
);

wp_list_pages( $args );
```

The problem is that by default this also shows the published children of draft pages, like so :

> Page 1 (published) -> displayed
>
> --- Page 2 (draft) -> not displayed
>
> ------ Page 3 (published) -> displayed

What I would like to achieve is :

> Page 1 (published) -> displayed
>
> --- Page 2 (draft) -> not displayed
>
> ------ Page 3 (published) -> **not** displayed

I suspect a custom Walker would do the trick, but I could never really understand how those work..

Is there a way to hide those child pages without having to set them all to draft ?

**Edit**:

To clarify, let's try some imagery. So you have a tree with the complete hierarchy of your pages. We are climbing up the tree. The moment we encounter a a draft branch, we cut it down. Naturally all the other branches attached to it further along are also discarded (no matter if they are drafts or not). I hope that explains it better.

Here is an example with a somewhat deep hierarchy :

> Page 1 (published) -> displayed
>
> --- Page 2 (draft) -> not displayed <- **Cut here and exclude all further children**
>
> ------ Page 3 (published) -> not displayed
>
> --------- Page 4 (published) -> not displayed
>
> ------------ Page 5 (draft) -> not displayed
>
> --------------- Page 6 (published) -> not displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great answers above. I took on the challenge trying to find yet another way to solve this.

### The `exclude` parameter:

We could try:

```
'exclude' => wpse_exclude_drafts_branches()
```

where:

```
function wpse_exclude_drafts_branches()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $exclude = array();
    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} where post_status = 'draft' AND post_type = 'page' " );
    $exclude = array_merge( $exclude, $results) ;
    while ( $results ):
        $results = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_parent > 0 AND post_parent IN (" .  join( ',', $results ) . ") " );
        $exclude = array_merge( $exclude, $results) ;
    endwhile;
    return join( ',', $exclude );
}
```

and the number of queries depends on the tree depth.

**Update:**

### The `exclude_tree` parameter:

I just noticed the `exclude_tree` parameter mentioned on the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages), so I wonder if this would work (untested) to exclude the whole of the *draft* nodes branches:

```
$exclude = get_posts(
    array( 
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'post_status'    => 'draft',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
   )
);
```

and then use:

```
'exclude_tree' => join( ',', $exclude ),
```

with `wp_list_pages()`.

Comment: That's nice and short. I think you should implode $exclude before returning, the exclude parameter of wp_list_pages() does't accept an array.

Comment: @mike23 thanks, I updated the answer ;-)

Comment: I wonder if we can simplify this much more with the `exclude_tree` parameter, to exclude the whole draft branches.

Comment: I can confirm that `exclude_tree` option you suggested in your update does work. Which really is kind of funny, considering the amount of code that has been produced to answer this question. I feel this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ialocin oh, it's maybe not as elegant and deep as the other solutions you and G.M. provided, but I'm glad to hear it works ;-) I'm not sure why I didn't notice this parameter  before on the Codex page, but I guess that can happen when putting the nose too deep into the source code instead ;-)

Comment: Ok, maybe its not as fancy of a solution :) But its built-in and only needs about 8 extra lines code, so thats actually not that bad. I guess you are right, that is what happens.. ;)

Comment: I removed my prev comment because now this works. And +1. What `exclude_tree` does is what @ialocin did in his code: to call `get_page_children` inside a loop. Now that function [recursively call itself].(http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_id_list/). Inside a for loop of possibly hundrends of posts. Result: to do this task 8 lines are required, but is possible that dozen of hundrends functions are called. I have no doubt that this is the right WordPress way, but as someone said in The Loop: *"nobody does things the f**king WordPress way... and thank God for that!"*

Comment: Yea, the almighty WordPress way... ;) @G.M.

Comment: @G.M. I guess the ways of WordPress are inscrutable ;-) Thanks, I also removed my related comment. It looks like there was a bug in `exclude_tree` with multiple arguments that was reported 6 years ago but it was fixed 5 months ago according to this [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9153).

Comment: Wow I had no idea exclude_tree existed. In the end it seems this answer is the simplest, thanks all for the great code, I'm learning a lot from it.

Answer (score 4):

Sincerly I found custom walkers annoying: sometimes what can be done with a simple filter require an entire class to coded and, but probably it's me, I don't really like logic behind WordPress walkers.

This is the reason why I often use a trick to filter elements before they are *walked*. It is a really simple Walker class:

```
class FilterableWalker extends Walker {

  private $walker;

  function __construct( Walker $walker ) {
    $this->walker = $walker;
  }

  function walk( array $elements = null, $max_depth = null ) {
    $args = func_get_arg( 2 );
    $filtered = apply_filters( 'filterable_walker_elements', $elements, $args, $this );
    if ( is_array( $filtered ) ) {
      $walk_args = func_get_args();
      $walk_args[0] = $filtered ;
      return call_user_func_array( array( $this->walker, 'walk' ), $walk_args );
    }
    return call_user_func_array( array( $this->walker, 'walk' ), func_get_args() );
  }

  function getWalker() {
    return $this->walker;
  }

  function getWalkerClass() {
    return get_class( $this->getWalker() );
  }
}
```

This is an all-purpose, reusable walker that enable filtering items before they are passed to *real* walker that must be passed in constructor.

In your case, you should do something like:

```
$args = array(
  'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
  'title_li' => '',
  'post_status'  => 'publish',
  'skip_draft_children' => 1, // <- custom argument we will use in filter callback
  'walker' => new FilterableWalker( new Walker_Page ) // <-- our walker
);

$pages = wp_list_pages( $args );
```

Now you can code a filter callback to filter pages using `'filterable_walker_elements'` hook fired by `FilterableWalker` class:

```
add_filter( 'filterable_walker_elements', function( $elements, $args, $filterable ) {

  $walker = $filterable->getWalkerClass();

  if (
    $walker === 'Walker_Page'
    && isset( $args['skip_draft_children'] )
    && $args['skip_draft_children'] // <-- our custom argument
  ) {
    $ids = array_filter( array_unique( wp_list_pluck( $elements, 'post_parent' ) ) );
    $parents = get_posts(
      array(
        'post__in' => $ids,  'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields'   => 'ids', 'post_type'   => 'page',
        'nopaging' => true
      )
    );
    $pages = $elements;
    foreach( $pages as $i => $page ) {
      if ( $page->post_parent !== 0 && ! in_array( $page->post_parent, $parents, true ) ) {
        unset($elements[$i]);
        $self_i = array_search( $page->ID, $parents, true );
        if ( $self_i !== FALSE ) unset( $parents[$self_i] );
      }
    }
  }
  return $elements;

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer ! Although it doesn't seem to do what I'm after. I am displaying a sitemap of pages (like a tree), whenever we arrive at a page that is in draft, I want to stop showing any other page further down in the hierarchy of that particular branch. I'll try to fiddle with your code to see what I can find.

Comment: @mike23 I edited the answer, now it should work. Before editing only direct children of a draft pages were removed, now any page down in the hierarchy of a draft page should be removed.

Comment: @G.M. Does this work no matter at which depth the first draft page is ?

Comment: @mike23 yes, absolutely

Answer (score 3):

Making use of a custom `Walker` is actually not that hard, it basically goes like this:

- Create a [class](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php);

  > A class is a collection of variables and functions working with these variables.
- By [extending](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) another one;

  > The extended or derived class has all variables and functions of the base class [...] and what you add in the extended definition.
- Like this:

  ```
  class Extended_Class extends Base_Class {
     // code
  }
  ```
- Which gives you the possibility to change/extend the [methods aka functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4841628/2505105) of the base class that has been extended. Additionally you can/could extend by adding methods or variables to the extended class.
- To fully understand and make use of the possibilities it is necessary to get deeper into [OOP: Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) aspects of PHP. But that would be too much here and not the rightplace anyway.

So lets get back to WordPress and [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages). The class we want to extend to make use of with `wp_list_pages()`, the [`Walker_Page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Page) class - [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1232) -, itself has been derived by extending the class [`Walker`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) - [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L14).

Following the above explained schema we are going to do the same:

```
class Wpse159627_Walker_Page extends Walker_Page {
    // code
}
```

Now `Walker_Page` has two variables - `$tree_type` and `$db_fields` - and four methods - `start_lvl()`, `end_lvl()`, `start_el()` and `end_el()`. The variables won't concern us, regarding the methods we are at least have to take a closer look at [`start_el()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1284) and [`end_el()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1365).

The first thing to see is that those two methods have the parameter `$page`:

> @param object $page Page data object.

Which contains all the relevant data we need, like the `post_parent`, and is pretty much a [`WP_Post`/`$post`/"`$page`"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post#Member_Variables_of_WP_Post) object. Given back by the [`get_pages()` return](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages#Return)

> An array containing all the Pages matching the request, or false on failure. The returned array is an array of "page" objects.

[inside](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1050) the `wp_list_pages()` function.

What we need to check is the post status of the current page parent, for doing this the function [`get_post_status()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status) is available. Like determined we can use the $page object available to do so.

```
$page_parent_id     = $page->post_parent;
$page_parent_status = get_post_status( $page_parent_id );
```

Now we can use this to check against the status of the currents page parent:

```
if ( $page_parent_status != 'draft' ) {
    // code
}
```

Lets implement it in our extended Walker class:

```
class Wpse159627_Walker_Page extends Walker_Page {
    function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0 ) {
        $page_parent_id     = $page->post_parent;
        $page_parent_status = get_post_status( $page_parent_id );
        if ( $page_parent_status != 'draft' ) {
            if ( $depth )
                $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            else
                $indent = '';

            extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
            $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);

            if( isset( $args['pages_with_children'][ $page->ID ] ) )
                $css_class[] = 'page_item_has_children';

            if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
                $_current_page = get_post( $current_page );
                if ( in_array( $page->ID, $_current_page->ancestors ) )
                    $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
                if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
                    $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
                elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
                    $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
            } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
            }

            $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

            if ( '' === $page->post_title )
                $page->post_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $page->ID );

            $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . '</a>';

            if ( !empty($show_date) ) {
                if ( 'modified' == $show_date )
                    $time = $page->post_modified;
                else
                    $time = $page->post_date;

                $output .= " " . mysql2date($date_format, $time);
            }
        }
    }
    function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $page_parent_id     = $page->post_parent;
        $page_parent_status = get_post_status( $page_parent_id );
        if ( $page_parent_status != 'draft' ) {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The new class can be used with `wp_list_pages()` like this:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'title_li'    => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'walker'      => new Wpse159627_Walker_Page
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
```

---

**Edit:**

Adding this for completeness reasons, so to make this work for trees, all descendants, not just children. It is *not the optimal way* to do it though, enough other suggestion have been made.

Because WordPress' `get_ancestors()` and `get_post_ancestors()` functions aren't made to get drafts too, I constructed a function to get every ancestor:

```
function wpse159627_get_all_post_ancestors( $post_id ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    $post = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'page_id'                => $post_id,
            'include'                => $post_id,
            'post_type'              => $post_type,
            'post_status'            => 'any',
            'cache_results'          => false,
            'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
            'update_post_term_cache' => false
        )
    );
    $post = $post->posts[0];

    if (
        ! $post
        || empty( $post->post_parent )
        || $post->post_parent == $post->ID
    ) {
        return array();
    }

    $ancestors = array();

    $id = $ancestors[] = $post->post_parent;

    while (
        $ancestor = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'page_id'                => $id,
                'include'                => $id,
                'post_type'              => $post_type,
                'post_status'            => 'any',
                'cache_results'          => false,
                'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
                'update_post_term_cache' => false
            )
        )
    ) {
    $ancestor = $ancestor->posts[0];
            if ( 
                empty( $ancestor->post_parent )
                || ( $ancestor->post_parent == $post->ID )
                || in_array( $ancestor->post_parent, $ancestors ) 
            ) {
                break;
            }

            $id = $ancestors[] = $ancestor->post_parent;
    }

    return $ancestors;
}
```

Additionally it is necessary to get the status of those ancestors. Which can be done with the following function:

```
function wpse159627_get_all_status( $ids ) {
    $status_arr = array();
    foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type( $id );
        $post = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'page_id'                => $id,
                'include'                => $id,
                'post_type'              => $post_type,
                'post_status'            => 'any',
                'cache_results'          => false,
                'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
                'update_post_term_cache' => false
            )
        );
        $post = $post->posts[0];
        $status_arr[] = $post->post_status;
        }
    return $status_arr;
}
```

This can be used to replace above explained conditional:

```
$ancestors = wpse159627_get_all_post_ancestors( $page->ID );
$ancestors_status = wpse159627_get_all_status( $ancestors );
if ( ! in_array( 'draft', $ancestors_status ) ) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is that `get_post_status` called for each element will trigger a DB query. And a DB query for every page is not a great thing if there are a lot of pages...

Comment: Sure, its not quite optimal, but believe me if I would be as knowledgeable as you are I would have suggested a solution as smart as yours. @G.M.

Comment: I just hate walkers, and you don't, so I had to find a solution to don't use them :) And believe me, you are enough knowledgeable to answer questions far better than me :)

Comment: Ok, lets agree we are both somewhat capable :) My feeling towards walkers just indifferent :) Aside from that reading through source plus documentation and answering questions is just another way for me to learn a bit more about the matter. @G.M.

Comment: That's a whole tutorial you wrote ! :) I'll see if I can make it work, for now just copypasta doesn't solve the problem.. I still see published pages whose parents are in draft.

Comment: I was in the mood to write something comprehensive :) I actually did not run the code myself, but I'm certain that the children aren't shown. I suppose what you mean is that not whole tree gets discarded, meaning that grandchildren and so forth aren't filtered out. But, not to be nit-picky, your question doesn't say anything about trees and grandchildren or all descendants, it does say children though. So the only thing I can say is, you have to specify you requirements exactly to get an exact answer. @mike23

Answer (score 2):

This answer is offering another way of doing this. The code is pretty much self-explaining, I named everything pretty literal to make it better understandable. What I did is constructing a function that determines the draft pages and their descendants, which than can be used with the `exclude` parameter of `wp_list_pages()`.

**Helper Function:**

```
function wpse159627_exclude_draft_sub_trees() {
    $pages_any_status = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'              => 'page',
            'post_status'            => 'any',
            'posts_per_page'         => -1,
            // make this as inexpensive as possible
            'cache_results'          => false,
            'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
            'update_post_term_cache' => false
        )
    );
    $draft_posts_ids = array_filter(
        array_map(
            function ( $array_to_map ) {
                if( $array_to_map->post_status == 'draft' ) {
                    return $array_to_map->ID;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            },
            $pages_any_status
        )
    );
    $children_of_draft_posts_arr_of_obj = array();
    foreach ( $draft_posts_ids as $draft_id ) {
        $children_of_draft_posts_arr_of_obj[] = get_page_children(
            $draft_id,
            $pages_any_status
        );
    }
    $children_of_draft_posts = array();
    foreach ( $children_of_draft_posts_arr_of_obj as $object ) {
        foreach ( $object as $key => $value ) {
            $children_of_draft_posts[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $children_of_draft_posts_ids = array_map(
        function ( $array_to_map ) {
            return $array_to_map->ID;
        },
        $children_of_draft_posts
    );
    $exclude_from_list_pages = array_merge(
        $draft_posts_ids,
        $children_of_draft_posts_ids
    );
    $exclude_comma_sep_list = implode(',',$exclude_from_list_pages);
    return $exclude_comma_sep_list;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$args = array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'title_li'    => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'exclude'     => wpse159627_exclude_draft_sub_trees()
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
```

---

If you are on a PHP version smaller than 5.3 you need a version without closures. In my book, to say that clearly, it is a mistake to operate on anything below 5.4. But I'm very well aware of the WordPress requirements, PHP 5.2.4, so here you go:

```
function wpse159627_extract_ids( $array_to_map ) {
    return $array_to_map->ID;
}
function wpse159627_extract_ids_of_drafts( $array_to_map ) {
    if( $array_to_map->post_status == 'draft' ) {
        return $array_to_map->ID;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
function wpse159627_exclude_draft_sub_trees_old_php() {
    $pages_any_status = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'              => 'page',
            'post_status'            => 'any',
            'posts_per_page'         => -1,
            // make this as inexpensive as possible
            'cache_results'          => false,
            'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
            'update_post_term_cache' => false
        )
    );
    $draft_posts_ids = array_filter(
        array_map(
            'wpse159627_extract_ids_of_drafts',
            $pages_any_status
        )
    );
    $children_of_draft_posts_arr_of_obj = array();
    foreach ( $draft_posts_ids as $draft_id ) {
        $children_of_draft_posts_arr_of_obj[] = get_page_children(
            $draft_id,
            $pages_any_status
        );
    }
    $children_of_draft_posts = array();
    foreach ( $children_of_draft_posts_arr_of_obj as $object ) {
        foreach ( $object as $key => $value ) {
            $children_of_draft_posts[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $exclude_from_list_pages = array_merge(
        $draft_posts_ids,
        $children_of_draft_posts_ids
    );
    $exclude_comma_sep_list = implode(',',$exclude_from_list_pages);
    return $exclude_comma_sep_list;
}
```